# vbaのFindで,行を指定して下から上へ検索したい。

Tags: vba

vbaの右端から,(FindNext,FindPrevious,after他)メソッドでできますか。
(参考)Range.Find メソッド (Excel)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

```
Sub atest()
    Dim Moji As String
    Dim iAtta As Long
    Moji = "宝物"
    Cells(2, 2) = Moji
    Cells(2, 3) = Moji
    Call myFind右端から(Moji, 2, iAtta)
    MsgBox Moji & "は" & Cells.Find(Moji).Column & "列目にありました。" & vbCrLf & _
           Moji & "は最後" & iAtta & "列目にありました。"
End Sub
Sub myFind右端から(Moji As String, iGyome As Long, iAtta As Long)
    For i = Cells(iGyome, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(Cells(iGyome, i), Moji) > 0 Then
           iAtta = i
           Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
       MsgBox iGyome & "行目に「" & Moji & "」を入れて下さい。"
       End
End Sub
'宝物は2列目にありました｡
'宝物は最後3列目にありました｡
```

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
20180420　追加
vbaのFindで,行を指定して下から上へ検索したい。
(参考)Findで下から上へ検索したい
http://www.relief.jp/docs/excel-vba-find-from-bottom.html

```
Sub atest()
    Dim Moji As String
    Moji = "宝物"
    Cells(2, 2) = Moji
    Cells(2, 3) = Moji
    MsgBox Moji & "は" & Rows(2).Find(Moji).Column & "列目にありました。" & vbCrLf & _
           Moji & "は最後" & Rows(2).Find(What:=Moji, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column & "列目にありました。"
End Sub
'宝物は2列目にありました｡
'宝物は最後3列目にありました｡
```

SearchDirection:=xlPreviousで解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: もう少し具体的に、どういった状況でどういったことがしたいのかを詳しく追記して頂けませんでしょうか？　タイトルだけでは mrrclb48z さんがどのような問題を解決したいのかが分かりにくいと思います。

Comment: ⭐️星マーク1は何を意味しているのでしょうか？

Comment: お気に入りされた数です。　／　スタック・オーバーフローの使い方についての質問は、[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)で出来るのでご活用ください。

Comment: 自己解決した場合、質問文に回答を書くのではなく、[自己回答する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)ことが勧められています。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: >質問をすると必ずページの下部にチェックボックスがあります。見当たりません。

Comment: それは質問と同時に回答する場合の説明ですね（分かりにくくてすいません）。現在はそのまま回答して頂ければ自己回答の形になります。